# Check if user and password exist and return true or false

Tags: mysql, go

I've already created a register system and now i want users to be able to login. So i'm trying to create a function to check if the username and password typed are correct, I'm new to programming and i'm struggling to understand how it should be handled.

I'm using this code:

```
func sqlLogin(username string, password string, db *sql.DB) bool{
    result, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM `users1` WHERE `username` = '%s' and password = '%s'", username, password))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return false
    } else {
        fmt.print(result)
        return true
    }
```

db.query doesn't return different values with this code even if i use correct vs wrong combination. How should i handle it?

Comment: when there is an error, what does `log.Fatal(err)` print?

Comment: you should not store passwords in the database.  instead, you store a hashed version of the password with a random salt attached.  then to check the password, you *read* that from the database, apply the salt to hash the entered password, and see if it matches the hash in the database.

Comment: here's a tutorial that has the elements you need, though I can't vouch for its accuracy, it's just the first thing google turned up: https://medium.com/@jcox250/password-hash-salt-using-golang-b041dc94cb72

Comment: In addition to not storing passwords in plaintext, use parameterized queries instead of Sprintf. See [the example in the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#example-DB.QueryContext) and google "SQL injections" to understand why this is very important.

Comment: Please don't do this. Don't do anything like this. Learn about how to securely manage credentials, or don't manage credentials at all. There's always OAuth.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to change your function to be like this, so that you can catch errors from the query even if they're not related to the login failure.

```golang
func sqlLogin(username string, password string, db *sql.DB) (bool, error) {
    result, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM `users1` WHERE `username` = ? and password = ?", username, password)
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        return false, nil
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return false, err
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
    return true, nil
}
```

Comment: This also has an sql injection vulnerability.   You should fix it.  The world doesn't need one more bad example of sql injection vulnerability code